# I have a custom UIView embed in WKWebview, how to set uiDelegate and navigationDelegate let webview didFinish function work?

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, wkwebview

I have a custom UIView with WKWebview.
And I found my webview delegate function `webView didFinish`、`didReceive` not work.
I print `OK` in `webView didFinish` but I found my local file already load.
What's wrong with my code?
Thanks.

```
public class CustomWebView: UIView{
    
    @objc public var webview: WKWebView?
    public var customDelegate: CustomDelegate?
    
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        loadXib()
    }
    
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: coder)
        loadXib()
    }
    
    func loadXib(){
        let bundle = Bundle(for: type(of: self))
        let nib = UINib(nibName: "\(Self.self)", bundle: bundle)
        
        let source = "var devicePlatform = 'iOS';"    
        let userScript = WKUserScript(source: source, injectionTime: .atDocumentStart, forMainFrameOnly: true)

        let userContentController = WKUserContentController()
        userContentController.add(self, name: "test")
        userContentController.addUserScript(userScript)

        let config = WKWebViewConfiguration()                        
        config.userContentController = userContentController
        
        if #available(iOS 9.0, *) {
            config.applicationNameForUserAgent = "Custom_APP"
        } else {
            
        }
        
        self.webview = WKWebView(frame: self.bounds, configuration: config)
        
        guard let wView = self.webview else { return }
        
        wView.uiDelegate = self as? WKUIDelegate
        wView.navigationDelegate = self
        wView.scrollView.bounces = false
        wView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        wView.allowsBackForwardNavigationGestures = true
        wView.configuration.preferences.setValue(true, forKey: "allowFileAccessFromFileURLs")
        
        wView.evaluateJavaScript("navigator.userAgent") { (result, error) in
            if let userAgent = result as? String, error == nil {
                print("===) uA : \(userAgent)")
            }
        }
                
        addSubview(wView)
    }
    
    
}

extension CustomWebView {
    
    public func start(){
        
        guard let webview = self.webview else { return }
        
        if Custom_Constants.IS_LOAD_LOCAL_HTML_FILE {
            guard let url = URL(string: Custom_Constants.BASE_URL) else { return }
            webview.loadFileURL(url, allowingReadAccessTo: url.deletingLastPathComponent())
        } else {
            guard let request = getRequest() else { return }
            webview.load(request)
        }
                
    }
    
    public func doHybridNativeRequest(request:NativeRequest){
        self.webview?.evaluateJavaScript("native2Web(\(request.getParameter()))", completionHandler: nil)
    }
    
    func doActionType(response:WebResponse){
        
        let actionName = response.name
        
        if actionName == "backToApp" {
            customDelegate?.goBackToApp?(webView: self, webResponse: response)
        }
        
        if actionName == "storeData" {
            customDelegate?.storeData?(webView: self, webResponse: response)
        }
        
        if actionName == "retrieveData" {
            customDelegate?.retrieveData?(webView: self, webResponse: response)
        }
      
    }
    
    func filterWebResponse(message:WKScriptMessage, response:WebResponse){
        
        if message.name == "test" {
            doActionType(response: response)
        }
    }
}

extension CustomWebView{
    
    fileprivate func getRequest() -> URLRequest? {
        var request: URLRequest?
        if let url = URL(string: "\(Custom_Constants.BASE_URL)") {
            print("===) url here: \(url)")
            request = URLRequest(url: url, cachePolicy: .reloadIgnoringLocalCacheData, timeoutInterval: 180)
        }
        return request
    }
}

extension CustomWebView : UIWebViewDelegate{
    
    public func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, runJavaScriptAlertPanelWithMessage message: String, initiatedByFrame frame: WKFrameInfo, completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void) {
    
    }
    
    public func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, runJavaScriptConfirmPanelWithMessage message: String, initiatedByFrame frame: WKFrameInfo, completionHandler: @escaping (Bool) -> Void) {
        
        let alertController = UIAlertController(title: nil, message: message, preferredStyle: .alert)
        
        alertController.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "YES", style: .default, handler: { (action) in
            completionHandler(true)
        }))
        
        alertController.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "NO", style: .default, handler: { (action) in
            completionHandler(false)
        }))
        
        
    }
}

extension CustomWebView: WKNavigationDelegate{
    
    public func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didFail navigation: WKNavigation!, withError error: Error) {

        self.customDelegate?.errorHasOccurred?(error: error)
        printLog("===) webView didFail....")
    }
    
    public func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didFinish navigation: WKNavigation!) {
        print("===) OK")
        self.customDelegate?.webviewDidFinish?(webview: webView, navigation: navigation)
    }
}

extension CustomWebView: WKScriptMessageHandler{
    
    public func userContentController(_ userContentController: WKUserContentController, didReceive message: WKScriptMessage) {
        
        guard let getDict = message.body as? Dictionary<String, Any> else{
            return;
        }
     
        print("===) \(message.body)")
        
        let response:WebResponse = WebResponse(parameter: getDict)
                
        filterWebResponse(message: message, response: response)

    }
}
```